# counting pairs in a list

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, mutablemap

I've recently started on HackerRank and I'm attempting "Sales by Match". I've arrived at a solution I'm content with in terms of exploiting Kotlin's function programming capabilities. However, I'm not getting the expected answer...

Problem summary:

> Given an Array:
> -> find and return the total number of pairs.

> ***i.e:***
>
> *input* **->** [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
>
> **number of pairs** **->** 3

---

here is my code and some comments to explain it:

```
fun sockMerchant(n: Int, pile: Array<Int>): Int{
    var count = 0
    mutableMapOf<Int, Int>().withDefault { 0 }.apply {
        // the [attempted] logic behind this piece of code here is 
        // that as we iterate through the list, the 'getOrPut()'
        // function will return either the value for the given [key]             
        // or throw an exception if there is no such key
        // in the map. However, since our map was created by 
        // [withDefault], the function resorts to its `defaultValue` <-> 0
        // instead of throwing an exception.
        for (e in values) {
            // this simplifies our code and inserts a zero [+1] where needed.
            // if (key exists)
            //      // return its associated value and MOD it:
            //      case: even  -> increment counter
            //            else  -> do nothing
            // else if (key dne)
            //      // insert default value <-> [0] + 1
            //              ....
            //              ....
            //              ....
            if (getOrPut(e, { getValue(e) + 1 } ) % 2 == 0) count++
        }
    }
    return count
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val n = scan.nextLine().trim().toInt()
    val ar = scan.nextLine().split(" ").map{ it.trim().toInt() }.toTypedArray()
    val result = sockMerchant(n, ar)
    println(result)
}
```

--
Any help or tips would go a long way here:)

Comment: What does the `n` variable mean?

Comment: Also there only appears to be two pairs in your sample input. What is the definition of a pair?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip - I see three pair: (10, 10), (10, 10), and (20, 20).

Comment: @AdamMillerchip the size of the list

Comment: @Todd depends on the definition of a pair, which is why I asked. But since the OP liked your answer, I guess you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified it a bit to be more easily testable, but here is the fixes :

```
import java.util.*

fun sockMerchant(n: Int, pile: Array<Int>): Int{
    var count = 0
    mutableMapOf<Int, Int>().withDefault { 0 }.apply {
        // the [attempted] logic behind this piece of code here is
        // that as we iterate through the list, the 'getOrPut()'
        // function will return either the value for the given [key]
        // or throw an exception if there is no such key
        // in the map. However, since our map was created by
        // [withDefault], the function resorts to its `defaultValue` <-> 0
        // instead of throwing an exception.
        for (e in pile) {
            // this simplifies our code and inserts a zero [+1] where needed.
            // if (key exists)
            //      // return its associated value and MOD it:
            //      case: even  -> increment counter
            //            else  -> do nothing
            // else if (key dne)
            //      // insert default value <-> [0] + 1
            //              ....
            //              ....
            //              ....
            println(e)
            put(e, getValue(e) + 1)
            if (getValue(e) % 2 == 0) count++
            println(entries)
        }
    }
    return count
}


val n = 5
val ar = "10 10 10 10 20 20 30 40".split(" ").map{ it.trim().toInt() }.toTypedArray()
val result = sockMerchant(n, ar)
println(result)
```

Output :

```
10
[10=1]
10
[10=2]
10
[10=3]
10
[10=4]
20
[10=4, 20=1]
20
[10=4, 20=2]
30
[10=4, 20=2, 30=1]
40
[10=4, 20=2, 30=1, 40=1]
3
Pair.kts:3:18: warning: parameter 'n' is never used
fun sockMerchant(n: Int, pile: Array<Int>): Int{
                 ^

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Explanation :

- You looped over "values", which is at start empty, so you never did anything with your  code
- Even when looping over `pile`, your incrementation logic didn't go above 1, so the condition was never satisfied and the count was never incremented.

But the main reasoning behind was correct.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this by grouping the numbers together, taking the resulting lists, and summing how many pairs each one contains:

```
fun sockMerchant(n: Int, pile: Array<Int>): Int =
    pile.groupBy { it }.values.sumBy { it.size / 2 }
```

After we do `pile.groupBy { it }`, we have this structure:

```
{10=[10, 10, 10, 10], 20=[20, 20, 20], 30=[30], 50=[50]}
```

We take the values, and sum by each of their size dividing by 2. This will round half-pairs down to 0 and full pairs to 1 each.

*Note:* I am not entirely clear what the purpose of `n` is in this case.